# Как правильно передать аргументы в нужный метод в C#? (Библиотека xNet)

Tags: c#, .net

```
MultiThreading rst = new MultiThreading();

rst.ThreadCount = 10;

rst.Run(num, fname, lname, MyAction);


public void MyAction (int number, string strf, string strl)
{
    //код (не важно)
}
```

Ошибка: Ни одна из перегрузок метода "Run" не принимает "4" аргументов

Почему аргументы передаются в метод: Run а не в метод: MyAction?

По руководству библиотеки xNet синтаксис: rst.Run(num, fname, lname, MyAction); правильный, в чем тут ошибка подскажите пожалуйста...

Comment: При чем тут библиотека xNet, если она служит для построения запросов. Может Вы ещё что то используете?

Comment: нет из библиотек тока xNet частично использую...

Comment: `По руководству библиотеки xNet` - А можно увидеть это руководство, ибо я уже пол часа "гуглю", так толком нечего и не нашел. Даже поиск по [исходному коду](https://github.com/X-rus/xNet/search?q=MultiThreading&unscoped_q=MultiThreading) не дал результатов.

Comment: Откуда Вы взяли класс MultiThreading?

Comment: Я так понимаю вы хотите воспользоваться тасками...потому что именно их запускают с помощью run(). Создайте несколько потоков с помощью класса thread. Сделайте чтобы ваша функция стала таском (гуглить Task) и потом каждый таск добавляйте в пул потоков с помощью метода run().

Comment: инструкции я тоже не нашел в сети чет, я давно делал копию на электронную книгу (там и смотрел) ток в то время была на сайте автора, да мне библиотека и не важна так то , сделай ответ с примером на основе выше кода если не трудно

Comment: @GeneratorSveta такие проблемы у вас, скорее всего из за того, что метод `Run` написан не вами ! Из приведённого вами примера нельзя что-то конкретно сказать, ибо не указаны вызываемые методы. Теперь отвечу на вопросы заданные другими пользователями, код взят из декомпилятора - от туда и вопросы.

Comment: какой код взят из декомпилятора?)) вы о чем?

Comment: @GeneratorSveta какая версия библиотеки xNet? и зачем её вообще использовать ? библиотека не обладает асинхронными методами, и полностью состоит из статических методов. Ответьте, что вы конкретно хотите сделать, возможно это в априори не возможно !!!

Comment: версия библиотеки 3.1.4.0 , хочу в 10 или более потоках запустить метод MyAction с переданными аргументами...

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример использования библиотеки xNet, для того чтоб @GeneratorSveta понял почему метод Run не принимает аргументы !

```
class Threads
{
    private List<Thread> _threads;

    public void Run(int countThreads)
    {
        _threads = new List<Thread>();

        for (int i = 0; i < countThreads; i++)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(multiThread);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            _threads.Add(thread);
            _threads[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public void Abort()
    {
        foreach (Thread thread in _threads)
        {
            thread.Abort();
        }
        _threads.Clear();
    }
    private void multiThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // здесь исполняемый код в потоке
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: то что метод Run не принимает аргументы я в курсе, мне нужно чтобы не метод Run принял а метод MyAction и работал в 10 потоках , читай внимательней выше код, это код на основе документаций библиотеки, по сути нужно выполнить метод MyAction в 10 потоках на пример и хотел по проще вариант реализовать такое по этому и остановился на xNet...